# Remove padding from unordered list

Tags: css

Something has bugged me for years. If you look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gmZa/2/)

you'll see a simple unordered list with some padding on the a element and a background colour to create a box.

There is white space between each item in the list. How can you get rid of it so the boxes are touching horizontally?

Html is:

```
<div id="dvLinks">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">One</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css is:

```
#dvLinks ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list - style - type: none;
}
#dvLinks ul li {
    display: inline;
}
#dvLinks ul li a {
    text - decoration: none;
    padding: .1em 1em;
    color: #000;
    background-color: # 33EEDD;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [It's very simple:](http://jsfiddle.net/Kh8BH/)

### CSS

```css
#dvLinks ul li { display: table-cell; }
```

---

### RESULTS

[image: Results]

Comment: Wow, so many ways to do this. Thanks for that, seems the simplest to me.

Comment: @MartinSmellworse - Yea, there are. I'm a fan of simple and clean.

Answer (score 5):

There are several ways. A few are:

1) Remove thew white space between the list item elements:

```
<li><a href="#">One</a></li><li><a href="#">Two</a></li><li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3gmZa/4/)**

2) Put HTML comments between the list item elements

```
<li><a href="#">One</a></li><!--
--><li><a href="#">Two</a></li><!--
--><li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/E9Ap3/)**

3) Float them left:

```
#dvLinks ul li {
    display: inline;
    float:left;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2kEVL/)**

Answer (score 3):

`inline` leaves white-space between elements.

Write elements on same line rather than writing them on different lines.

Change

```
<li><a href="#">One</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
```

to

```
<li><a href="#">One</a></li><li><a href="#">Two</a></li><li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/3gmZa/3/)

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the `ul` `font-size` to 0 and then you have to set the `font-size` of the `li` in what ever your like

```
#dvLinks ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 0;
}

#dvLinks ul li { display: inline; font-size: 16px; }

#dvLinks ul li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .1em 1em;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #33EEDD;
}
```

See the [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/3gmZa/7/)

This is a common problem with the inline/inline-block.

Another solution is the following:

```
// All elements in one line
<ul><li>Element #1</li><li>Element #2</li>...</ul>

// Or
// No space between li elements
<ul><li>
    Element #1</li><li>
    Element #2</li>...
</ul>

// Or
// Comments between li elements
<ul><li>
    Element #1</li><!--
    --><li>Element #2</li><!--
    ...-->
</ul>

// Or by using CSS
// Change the li display attribute to
ul li
{
    display : table-cell;
}
```

Anyway, best solution for me is the float left. You can do it like that:

```
<ul id="list" class="clearfix">
    <li>Element #1</li>
    <li>Element #2</li>
    <li>Element #3</li>
</ul>
```

and in CSS

```
/* Clear fix resource : http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html */
.clearfix:after
{
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix
{
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix
{
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix
{
    height: 1%;
}

#list li
{
    display : block;
    float : left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use negative margins.

```
#dvLinks ul li { 
    margin: 0 -1px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add

```
li { margin-left: -5px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3gmZa/6/