# how to remove the padding in dropdown-menu list <a>?

Tags: css, html, dropdown

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right" style="margin-right: 25px;" >
                 <li><a href="#"> My Profile </a></li>
                 <li class="dropdown">
                 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                  My Blog <span class="caret"></span>
                  </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Sports</li></a>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                         <li><a href="#">Foods</li></a>
                         <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Entertainment</li></a>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                           <li><a href="#">Travel</li></a>
                  </ul>
                  </li>
```

how to delete the padding on my dropdown-menu list because its destroying the background color i put in there. This is the image of my current dropdown-list which having some problem on padding:

[image]

Comment: can your provide code for `class="divider"`

Comment: show your css file

Answer (score 2):

Here are few things

Incorrect html structure

```
<li><a href="#">Foods</li></a>
```

change it to

```
<li><a href="#">Foods</a></li>
```

show us the style for li, a and .divider
which one is using background: #809109;

I guess you need to remove padding of li

```
.dropdown-menu > li{
    padding:0px
}
```

or you can add background-color for li too

```
.dropdown-menu > li{
    background-color:#809109;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the problem statement is incomplete and the html syntax is faulty, still this problem can occur without those. The problem lies in inserting the divider or horizontal rule, whatever separator you are using. For these, the Unordered List tag adds additional padding which might be the case in this problem. You can use one of the methods mentioned in this answer to solve your problem:

[Remove padding from unordered list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20616334/remove-padding-from-unordered-list)