# Display <div> inline with list item

Tags: html, css

Given a following structure:

```
<div class="index">a</div>
<div class="li">
  <div class="index">b</div>
  <div class="li">
    some text
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to display it as this:

```
a b some text
```

and not:

```
a
  b 
    some text
```

The problem is that I am **not** allowed to change HTML markup, so it's a pure CSS question.

**EDIT:**
"li" must have `display` set to `list-item` or follow the list hierarchy in terms of margins on the left side

Comment: You can use `<span>`...

Comment: @Edward I am not allowed to change HTML markup unfortunatelly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `float` `.index` and `.li`

```css
.li { display: list-item; }
.index, .li {
   float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="index">a</div>
<div class="li">
  <div class="index">b</div>
  <div class="li">
    some text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited the question and added some more info. I tried the way you recommend, but it doesn't seem to work like I need. Even if I set `.index` to `inline` it still looks like `block`

Comment: @LeonidBor alright updated. you can use `float` instead

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried editing the css for the li class?

.li { display: table-cell; }

This is where I found that answer: [Remove padding from unordered list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20616334/remove-padding-from-unordered-list)

If that doesn't work, could you post the relevant sections of the CSS you are working with as well?